# Rspec Guard is running twice always

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I have been working with rspec and guard to run automatically my tests ones I save the file, but guard is running twice every time and I don´t figure it out why, I have seen in another posts that it is maybe because there is a duplicated config option in spec_helper.rb, but I think does is not my case. I leave below my spec_helper file content. Hope to know how to resolve this issue, it starts to take a long time waiting guard to run twice the same

Thanks

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.lint
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    reset_email
  end

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.include(MailerMacros)
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Comment: Show your Guardfile as well. And does it always duplicate all specs everytime? or only some?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `config.order = "random"` from `spec_helper.rb`

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have multiple files with the same name. Just rename your rake file which include the logic that run twice.

Keep in mind, there can be internal gem files which you do not have access to which can conflict with your Guardfile can cause duplicate execution.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading this *new* Wiki entry in `Guard`: https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Understanding-Guard

... simply because the above doesn't provide enough info to find the causes (and there are a few possible - like editors with backup file options, missing ignore rules, unsupported editor, slow filesystem, incorrect latency, bad rules in `Guardfile`, multiple watch rules matching, bug in `Guard`, etc.).

But that Wiki page can quickly help you drill down to the core cause.

If it is a `Listen` issue, check out the wiki here: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki
(especially the `LISTEN_GEM_DEBUGGING=1` environment variable to see if you're getting multiple events or multiple callback).

Once you have that info, you can submit an issue in `Guard` and we can work out the cause in your situation.